# zsh doesn't print the command received from standard input

Tags: zsh

When conveying commands to interactive zsh using standard input (run it with options `-i` and `-s`) it doesn't print the executed command itself, but prints command output immediately after the prompt sign:

```
$ echo "echo test" | zsh -si
% test
% $
```

While in normal interactive mode it should look like:

```
$ zsh -si
% echo test
test
%
```

The main issue here is that in the first case the output of `echo test` command occurs just after prompt message while it is expected to be printed from new line. I need this to test command line application which requires interactive environment and such behavior of `zsh` significantly complicates test output analysis.

Is there some way to run `zsh` in pipe so it will work exactly as in normal interactive mode?

Comment: The problem is that your shell exits as soon as standard input closes, which happens once the `echo` command completes and its end of the pipe is closed. You likely don't want a pipe, at least not an "unnamed" one. Can you provide more detail about how your application will be run for testing?

Comment: The command `echo "echo test" | zsh -si` is used just to reproduce the issue with minimum of code. In my case I run `zsh` using python `Popen` and send commands through pipe. The main issue is that commands output occurs after `%` sign, which complicates output checking.

Comment: Even a non-interactive shell reads its input line by line; are you sure you need an interactive shell? Don't confuse "interactive shell" with "interactive program run *from* a shell".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test a command line application as if it was interacting through a terminal, you need to run it in a terminal. Terminals have more capabilities than pipes, and many applications, including zsh, behave differently depending on whether their input is to a terminal.

Passing the option `-si` causes zsh to enable interactive features such as displaying a prompt while reading commands from the input. But it doesn't activate *terminal* interaction features such as echoing the input and processing key bindings.

The de facto standard for interacting with an application running in a terminal is [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) and its imitators. In Python, use [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```py
import pexpect
p = pexpect.spawn("zsh -f")
p.expect("% ")
p.sendline("echo test")
p.expect("test")
```